# an improper integral of real function without using complex analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I came across a problem in improper integrals of real functions:

Show that $$\int_3^5 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x-5)}}dx=3\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

I had trouble even to show that the improper integral is convergent. For, while trying to use a comparison theorem on the functions 
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x-5)}}\quad \text{and}\quad g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-3}},$$
the conditions of the theorem are not satisfied as $f(x)\notin\mathbb{R}$.

I finally conclude that the question is wrong or it needs complex analysis.

Any comment or clarification to my problem will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the conditions of the theorem are not satisfied".  Anyways, the integral does converge, just as $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}~\mathrm dx$ converges.

Comment: The condition that if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ and $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l<\infty$, then the improper integral of $f$ exist if that of $g$ exist.

Comment: I think you need to add the condition that that only needs to hold for $x$ in the domain of the integral.

Comment: But for $3\leq x\leq 5$, $f(x)\notin\mathbb{R}$ and I have no clue how to compare with any other function. By the way, thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: Oh, well yeah, that's probably a major typo.  They probably wanted $(5-x)$ instead of $(x-5)$.

Comment: Well, that must be it! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the most general problem of the integral

$$I=\int_a^b \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}\,dx$$ and looking at the integrand where $x$ is close to the bounds . Taylor expansions gives
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a-b} \sqrt{x-a}}+\frac{\left(3 a^2-4 a b\right) \sqrt{x-a}}{2
   (a-b)^{3/2}}+O\left((x-a)^{3/2}\right)$$
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{b-a} \sqrt{x-b}}+\frac{\left(3 b^2-4 a b\right) \sqrt{x-b}}{2
   (b-a)^{3/2}}+O\left((x-b)^{3/2}\right)$$  So, as Simply Beautiful Art commented, there is no problem of convergence.

Now, considering the problem of the antiderivative
$$J=\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}\,dx$$ use, as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner answered, [the third substitution of Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) that is to say 
$$\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b)}=t (x-a)\implies x=\frac{a t^2-b}{t^2-1}\implies dx=\frac{2 t (b-a)}{\left(t^2-1\right)^2}\,dt$$ which makes 
$$J=\int\frac{ -2\left(b-a t^2\right)^2}{\left(t^2-1\right)^3}\,dt$$ Now, use partial fraction decomposition for the integrand
$$\frac{ -2\left(b-a t^2\right)^2}{\left(t^2-1\right)^3}=-\frac{3 a^2+2 a b+3 b^2}{8 (t-1)}+\frac{3 a^2+2 a b+3 b^2}{8 (t+1)}+\frac{-5 a^2+2
   a b+3 b^2}{8 (t-1)^2}+\frac{-5 a^2+2 a b+3 b^2}{8 (t+1)^2}-\frac{a^2-2 a
   b+b^2}{4 (t-1)^3}+\frac{a^2-2 a b+b^2}{4 (t+1)^3}$$ and integrate termwise to get $$J=\frac{t (a-b)^2}{2
   \left(t^2-1\right)^2}-\frac{t \left(-5 a^2+2 a b+3 b^2\right)}{4 \left(t^2-1\right)}+\frac{1}{8} \left(3
   a^2+2 a b+3 b^2\right) \log \left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)$$ which makes $$I=-\frac{i \pi}8 (3 a^2+2 a b+3 b^2)$$

Using $a=3$ and $b=5$ would then lead to $$I=-\frac{33 i \pi }{2}$$

If the problem is$$\int_3^5 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)(5-x)}}\,dx=-i\int_3^5 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x-5)}}\,dx$$ the result  would be $$I=\frac{33  \pi }{2}$$

May I suspect a few typo's in the problem and the answer ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations @Claude Leibovici.

Comment: It surprises me that your efforts had not given your wonderful answer more upvotes than Dr. SG's.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Be sure that I appreciate your opinion ! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: use the Euler substitution with $$\sqrt{a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}=(x-\alpha)t$$

Answer (score 2):

Other substitution suggestion: $x = \cos\theta +4$ .

Comment: That works a great with the corrected question $\int_3^5 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)(5-x)}}dx=33\frac{\pi}{2}$ and made me realise this question is just a translation of a more standard one. Thanks ! (+1)